# How to set tags for sub router in swagger-jsdoc

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-jsdocs

I want to set sub tag for sub router in swagger-jsdoc.

I want to like this

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * tags:
 *  name: router1
 */
router.use('/router1', router1);
```

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * tags:
 *  - router1
 *  name: router2
 */
router.use('/router2', router2);
```

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * paths:
 *  /router1/router2/path
 *   get:
 *    tags:
 *     - router1/router2
 *    summary: "Get Something"
 */
router.get('/', getSomething);
```

Is there any way to do this?